# JS Create different arrays from CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a CSV which contains files like

```
kilo;1;
kome;3;
hell;5;
```

I want all numbers to be stored in an int array(JS)

```
var lines = content.split("\r");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var x = lines[i].split(";");
    }
    var A = [x[3]];
```

It saves each element as a different array!

Comment: Some more information would be nice how it's not really clear how your csv looks like.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. What is `lines` and `count`? What are expected results? Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl true I thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var lines = ["kilo;1;", "kome;3;", "hell;5;"]

var numbers = lines.map(line => +line.split(";")[1])

console.log(numbers)
```

or you can get all numbers from the string at once:

```js
var CSV = "kilo;1;\r\nkome;3;\r\nhell;5;"

var numbers = CSV.match(/[0-9]+/g)

console.log(numbers)
```

---

to sort, something like:

```js
var lines = ["kilo;1;", "kome;3;", "hell;5;"]

var result = lines.map(line => line.split(";")).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])

console.log(result)
```

---

As a side note, there are many table libraries like https://datatables.net/ that have sorting options:

```js
var lines = ["kilo;1;", "kome;3;", "hell;5;"]
var data = lines.map(line => line.split(';'))

$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data,
    columns: [ { title: "a" }, { title: "b" } ],
    order: [ 1, "asc" ],         // order by column 2 in ascending order
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    info: false,
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="display compact"/>
```

Comment: The first one can it reorder the words based on the numbers ex var lines = ["kilo;5;", "kome;1;", "hell;3;"] to output kome hell kilo?

Comment: Slai take a look at an important question:[stackoverflow.com/questions/46861439/reorder-csv-r‌​ows]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are referencing `count` in your for loop, but that doesn't exist and needs to be `i` instead. Also, you are populating your array after the loop, with only the latest value of `x`.

Here you can see a slightly changed working example:

```js
var csv = "kilo;1;\r\nkome;3;\r\nhell;5;",
    lines = csv.split("\r\n"),
    myIntArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var fields = lines[i].split(";");
    myIntArray.push(parseInt(fields[1], 10));
}

console.log(myIntArray);
```

Comment: and a question what does that 10 mean?